# Is it possible to run Carla simulator in a serverless manner on the cloud? (AWS in particular)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, serverless, carla

As part of my project, I need to run [Carla Simulator](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla) on the cloud. I'd be developing around it and I need to be able to use the cloud to run and record simulations.

One of the requirements is for the usage of the cloud to be as cheap as possible, hence the preferred direction of going serverless since EC2 instances are quite expensive, especially with the resources needed by Carla.

I have tried using a Fargate Launch type but discovered that it doesn't support GPU resources which are needed for Carla. EKS can use either Fargate or EC@ instances, the former has the same problem and the latter isn't an option due to cost. The only option I see with potential is using AWS Robomaker, which I've tried to use but am not sure if the Carla [images](https://hub.docker.com/r/carlasim/carla) and [Dockefiles](https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/tree/master/Util/Docker) Match the [requirments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/robomaker/latest/dg/container-requirements.html) for Robomaker. I'm not sure if this would even fulfil the needs of my project as Robomaker seems to have prohibitive limitations.

I'm not at all experienced with any other cloud providers but would be open to use them if there is a strong case for them against AWS.

Comment: In what way is EC2 too expensive and why would you assume anything else to be much cheaper? The resources / requirements will be expensive no matter where you deploy it.

Comment: Because I need to run and terminate simulations on demand, not constantly. The on-demand pricing for EC2 is more expensive than any other instance or service (as far as I understand)

Comment: A g3.4xlarge costs $1.14/hour, g4dn.4xlarge costs $1.204, both are less expensive than what one GPU hour unit costs in robomaker. You need hard number if you plan on comparing different services. E.g. what hardware do you actually need (GPU, RAM, CPU, disk), how many of it, for how long, ...?

Comment: You are absolutely right... that never occurred to me. Thanks so much.